# Why are operators different in different languages?

Tags: operators, programming-languages

Why do operators have different functions in different languages?

Answer (score 0):

Because different languages exist to solve different problems, are developed at different times by different people with different levels of knowledge, under different outside constraints.

Depending on what problems a language tries to solve (or tries to solve first), some of the easier characters to type might have already been used for more common or newer concepts by the time a new operator is added.

E.g. PHP wasn't an object-oriented language at first, so used `.` as the concatenation operator. Then they added object-oriented PHP, and now they needed a different operator for identifying fields.

OTOH in a language like HyperTalk, which doesn't have data structures, you do not need a field-resolution operator at all.